# For every 24hours i need to enable the UIButton,

Tags: iphone, xcode

Please help me out of this guys. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you try the code if yes then put your code over here.

Comment: You must put your answer with good explanation on SO. So it can be easy to answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple put the **NSTimer** for 24 hr Once timer will fire,make that button **ON**.Give your interval.

```
[NSTimer 
                             scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300 
                             target:self 
                             selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) 
                             userInfo:nil 
                             repeats:YES];
```

Fire Method:-

```
 - (void) timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *) theTimer { //Write Your Code Here }
```